# Continuity of covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose there exists a piecewise continously differentiable curve on a riemannian manifold. If at a point, the covariant derivative of the velocity vector field along the curve is continous, does it also imply that the curve is continously differentiable at that point?

Comment: The velocity vector is only defined along the curve, so it is not a vector field on the manifold.

Comment: By the term vector field along the curve, I mean a map from each point on the curve to a tangent vector at that point. The velocity vector field along the curve takes each point on the curve to the corresponding velocity vector of the curve at that point. I got the term from do carmo's book on riemannian geometry .

Answer (score 0):

If continuity is measured by one-sided limits, no: The path $\gamma(t) = (t, |t|)$ in the plane satisfies $D_{\gamma'}\gamma' = 0$ *everywhere* (in the sense of having extant, equal one-sided limits at each point), but $\gamma$ is not continuously differentiable at the origin.

The same is true of any non-smooth piecewise-geodesic path.

Comment: I'm not sure about this example: Does $\gamma'$ even exist at $t=0$? I.e. you can fill the hole in the value of the derivative by analytic continuation, but the lhs isn't really well-defined. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You're right: $\gamma'(0)$ does not exist, hence "If continuity is measured by one-sided limits...". :) The only other interpretation of your question I could see was, "If $\gamma$ is differentiable, and if the covariant derivative $D_{\gamma'}\gamma'$ (exists and) is continuous, is $\gamma'$ continuous?" for which the answer is obviously "yes" since $D_{\gamma'} \gamma'$ involves differentiating $\gamma'$ a second time. If neither interpretation addresses what you're asking, could you please clarify your question?

Comment: It's not my question.... I was interpreting the question in the way you just described, so I was just surpised there would be a counterexample. But I think it's clear now.